# On Android support lib dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-support-library

It just occured to me why we add android support lib dependencies as remote dependencies to the compilation path in gradle scripts ? I mean we already have them installed on our local. So wouldn't it be more meaningful to declare them as local dependencies (ie: compile fileTree ... ). Or am I missing some important stuff ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Adding `compile "com.example.library:something:1.2.5"` to your gradle dependencies does not necessarily have to mean that this library needs to be taken from a remote source. It just means that your project relies on (*depends* on) this library.

During gradle sync, different sources (including local ones, caches, remote repositories, etc.) are searched to find the desired dependency.

Comment: I see. There's is reference [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) which particularly associates remote dependencies and the "compile" term. That's why I got confused.

Comment: Yep there is, but it's not really correct. I think the author had something different in mind and used term "remote" that (in this particular case) can be a bit misleading. I believe that author's intentions were more like `remote` as "not belonging to (and not included in) this project" than `remote` as "needed to be downloaded from a remote repository".

Comment: Interesting discussion - if you remove your jcenter() from your repositories, your project won't build; if you point to a library you don't currently have, Android Studio will almost forcefully download and install it for you; is this really local or remote?

Comment: If you remove your the `jcenter()` (and `mavenCentral()` and all other central repositories) and you request a library, that your gradle does not have cached (and gradle caches downloaded libraries across multiple projects), then you will get an error that `gradle failed` because it `could not find` a particular library. Also you will get a list of places that has been searched looking for a particular dependency.

Comment: @BartekLipinski No problem about that. Can you provide me some reference, if it's possible ?